# Wireless Driver for Broadcom BCM 4312 will not stay connected to a wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have a HP Pavillion dv6000 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and a Broadcom wireless card (BCM4312).

My Ethernet connection is fine. But when the wifi is turned on, it will stay connected for a short time and then disconnect and reconnect again. The wireless card is supposed to use the b43 driver, but it still does not hold the connection.

How can I fix my WiFi problem?

Comment: Is it in fact the driver b43? `lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43`.

Comment: this is the returned mssg:    wl                   6144840  0 
                                                    cfg80211              418839  1 wl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

Using the ethernet temporarily, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer   
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and tell us if the wireless is working as expected.